# Linked list Java: I wrote a method that is supposed to remove a node, but it isn't working

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to remove a node from my list, but the node doesn't disappear. This method is supposed to walk through the list and check if the toDelName == any name node. If it does then it will delete the node.

```
public static void removeName(String toDelName, Names list)
{
    Names current = list;

    while (current.next != null)
    {
        if (current.name.equalsIgnoreCase(toDelName))
        {
            current.prev.next = current.next;
            current.next.prev = current.prev;

        }
        current.prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is this a doubly Linked List?

Comment: what "is not working"? you'd better give some input, expected output, and actual output

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have originates from the line:

```
    current.prev = current;
```

You should delete that line. The reason being, that every time that line gets executed, current.prev gets set to current. Therefore, current.prev.next (which you try to assign inside your if-case) will, after the first iteration of the while-loop, always have the value current.next - your assignment

```
    current.prev.next = current.next;
```

therefore does nothing at all.

You probably tried to update your object with the name current somehow. However, this is not necessary in object oriented programming. The value current.prev points to changes as soon as current gets assigned to current.next.

Answer (score 0):

1. When your your condition is not matching, then move forward. So you dont need `current.prev = current;`.
2. Also you are not handling the condition when you need to delete the last node of the list.

   ```
   public void removeName(String toDelName, Names list) {
     Names current = list;

     while (current.next != null) {
       if (current.name.equalsIgnoreCase(toDelName)) {
         current.prev.next = current.next;
         current.next.prev = current.prev;
         return;
       }
       current = current.next;
     }

     if (current.name.equalsIgnoreCase(toDelName)) {
       current.prev.next = null;
     }
   }
   ```

// Print the list for checking.

```
    public static void print(Names start) {
      while (start != null) {
        System.out.println(start.getName());
        start = start.getNext();
      }
    }
```